# circuitpython set_ipv4_address issue pico w

Tags: adafruit-circuitpython

Getting the following error on set_ipv4_address line:

TypeError: extra positional arguments given

Code is below. Creating ipaddress objects as specified in the documentation for the wifi module. ipaddress objects are created correctly.

```
dic = {}
with open('PCATS_WID_CONFIG.ini') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
if line[0] is not '#':
line = line.strip()
key = line.split(':')[0].lower()
value = line.split(': ')[1]
dic[key] = value

ip = ipaddress.ip_address(dic["ip"])
netmask = ipaddress.ip_address(dic["netmask"])
gateway = ipaddress.ip_address(dic["gateway"])
#print(ip,netmask,gateway)

wifi.radio.set_ipv4_address(ip,netmask,gateway) # LINE ERROR OCCURS ON
wifi.radio.connect(dic["ssid"],dic["password"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ipv4 =  ipaddress.IPv4Address("192.168.1.101")
netmask =  ipaddress.IPv4Address("255.255.255.0")
gateway =  ipaddress.IPv4Address("192.168.1.1")
wifi.radio.set_ipv4_address(ipv4=ipv4,netmask=netmask,gateway=gateway)
```

Comment: This particular function was actually not yet implemented on the Pico W, however, I had also made a mistake with the code, which you have corrected here.

Now implemented and working with CircuitPython 8.0.0 beta 3